# All but one PHP Include File Works

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, include

I have some HTML5 files that I've converted to PHP (learning PHP). I put the head, header, nav, and footer sections of the HTML document into separate PHP include files. The head.php, header.php, and nav.php includes are working. The footer isn't. I have used the same path to footer.php as I have for the other three since they are all located in the same folder.

The footer needs the company contact information, copyright information (with my name as part of the copyright information), a terms of use link (currently just a place holder "#" address) and the current date formatted as Wednesday, September 6, 2017 and I'm using (or trying to use) the PHP date function to generate this date.

As an HTML5 document, the code looked something like this:

```
<aside class="address">
Company Name<br>
Street Address<br>
City, State Zip code<br>
Phone number<br>
Email address
</aside>
```

(Honestly I'm not sure why I did the aside class="address" thing...)

The other half of the footer code looks something like this:

```
<p class="footer-bar">&copy; 2017 All Rights Reserved | My Name | Company Name | <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> | <span id="wbdate"></span></p>
```

I used CSS3 to make the address appear to be in one column, and the rest of the footer in a second column that displays the other information straight across or soft breaks if the view is smaller.

(In case it's relevant, here is the CSS3 code:

```
footer {
margin-top: .5rem;
margin-left: -1rem;
padding: .5rem 1rem 1.25rem 0;
color: #7f1818;
}

footer aside {
width: 47%;
font-size: .6rem;
margin-top: -.1rem;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: .5rem;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

footer a {/*email address formatting*/
font-weight: bold;
color: #7f1818;
}

footer>p {
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
padding-right: 1rem;
font-size: .6rem;
text-align: center;
}
```

While ideally, I'd like to keep the footer in the same format, I'm not averse to the idea of displaying the address in a single row and the other information on the next row, but nothing I try gets the PHP include to work.

Here is what I have at the bottom of the main PHP document:

```
<footer>
<?php include 'modules/footer.php';?>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

(I know "modules" isn't the standard,but it's what I used for the time being)

The footer.php document looks something like this:

```
<aside class="address">
Contact Us: <br>
Street Address<br>
City, State Zipcode<br>
phone<br>
<a href="mailto:companyname@domain.com">Name</a>
</aside>
<p class="footer-bar">&copy; 2017 All Rights Reserved | Name | Company | 
<a href="#">Terms of Use</a> | <?php echo date("l", "F" "d", "Y"); ?></p>
```

I'm guessing since the other three includes are working just fine, the problem is with the content within the footer.php file, but I can't figure out what it is. :(

Can some PHP-savvy person, help me  figure out what I've done wrong?

Note: I added the javascript tag because in the HTML version, I just used the Javascript date function using an external javascript file (since more than one page needs the function.

```
<script src="js/currdate.js"></script>
```

And the code inside currdate.js is:

```
var currdate = new Date()
var daysnames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
var monthsnames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

var tday = daysnames[currdate.getDay()],
tmonth = monthsnames[currdate.getMonth()],
tdaynum = currdate.getDate(),
tyear = currdate.getFullYear();
var fdate = tday + ", " + tmonth + " " + tdaynum + " , " + tyear
document.getElementById ("wbdate").innerHTML = fdate
```

And it works just fine

Comment: Your call to the `date()` function is wrong. See the docs [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: ^ what he said `date("l", "F" "d", "Y");`

Comment: I think you should do some research on debugging php, or you'll be here quite often. Error reporting, die, var_dump, all tools that could have pointed you to the error if used correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the PHP date function in PHP docs
http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

You must use only one parameter as format:

```
<?php echo date("l, F d, Y"); ?>
```